# File system becoming read-only at random

Tags: boot, mount, hard-drive, read-only, dmesg

for some time now my OS has been switching to read-only mode seemingly at random. Typical fix for this problem was booting from live USB and running `fsck /dev/sda3/` and then I could boot up normally. Now I have grown tired of this and I want to fix it completely but I think it's just my HDD doing it since it has over 10 years of service behind him and there is no way of recovery completely. One time while booted to live USB I've run `sudo badblocks -v /dev/sda > ~/bad_sectors.txt` and then `sudo e2fsck -l bad_sectors.txt /dev/sda` thinking it would mark bad sectors (which there are around 1000) as unusable but to no avail. Here is the output of `dmesg --follow | grep sda` from the time of switching to read-only:

```
[13347.507892] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#20 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=4s
[13347.507900] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#20 Sense Key : Medium Error [current]
[13347.507905] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#20 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[13347.507910] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#20 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 44 d6 17 00 00 01 00 00
[13347.507912] I/O error, dev sda, sector 1154881384 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 2 prio class 0
[13347.507951] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#21 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=4s
[13347.507956] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#21 Sense Key : Medium Error [current]
[13347.507960] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#21 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[13347.507964] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#21 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 44 d6 18 00 00 01 00 00
[13347.507967] I/O error, dev sda, sector 1154881536 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 2 prio class 0
[13347.507984] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#23 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=2s
[13347.507988] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#23 Sense Key : Medium Error [current]
[13347.507992] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#23 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[13347.507996] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#23 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 5b 10 cc d8 00 00 08 00
[13347.507999] I/O error, dev sda, sector 1527827672 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[13347.508005] EXT4-fs warning (device sda3): ext4_end_bio:342: I/O error 10 writing to inode 55050469 starting block 190978459)
[13347.508013] Buffer I/O error on device sda3, logical block 189801883
[13347.508032] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#24 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=2s
[13347.508037] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#24 Sense Key : Medium Error [current]
[13347.508041] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#24 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[13347.508046] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#24 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 5b 10 cc e8 00 00 08 00
[13347.508049] I/O error, dev sda, sector 1527827688 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[13347.508054] EXT4-fs warning (device sda3): ext4_end_bio:342: I/O error 10 writing to inode 55050469 starting block 190978461)
[13347.508060] Buffer I/O error on device sda3, logical block 189801885
[13347.508072] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#25 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=2s
[13347.508076] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#25 Sense Key : Medium Error [current]
[13347.508080] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#25 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[13347.508085] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#25 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 5b 10 cc f8 00 00 08 00
[13347.508087] I/O error, dev sda, sector 1527827704 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[13347.508093] EXT4-fs warning (device sda3): ext4_end_bio:342: I/O error 10 writing to inode 55050469 starting block 190978463)
[13347.508098] Buffer I/O error on device sda3, logical block 189801887
[13347.508108] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#26 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=2s
[13347.508113] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#26 Sense Key : Medium Error [current]
[13347.508117] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#26 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[13347.508121] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#26 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 5b 10 cd 30 00 00 08 00
[13347.508124] I/O error, dev sda, sector 1527827760 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[13347.508129] EXT4-fs warning (device sda3): ext4_end_bio:342: I/O error 10 writing to inode 55050469 starting block 190978470)
[13347.508134] Buffer I/O error on device sda3, logical block 189801894
[13347.508145] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#27 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=2s
[13347.508149] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#27 Sense Key : Medium Error [current]
[13347.508153] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#27 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[13347.508158] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#27 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 5b 10 cd b0 00 00 08 00
[13347.508160] I/O error, dev sda, sector 1527827888 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[13347.508166] EXT4-fs warning (device sda3): ext4_end_bio:342: I/O error 10 writing to inode 55050469 starting block 190978486)
[13347.508171] Buffer I/O error on device sda3, logical block 189801910
[13347.508181] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#28 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=2s
[13347.508185] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#28 Sense Key : Medium Error [current]
[13347.508189] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#28 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[13347.508193] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#28 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 5b 10 ce 28 00 00 08 00
[13347.508195] I/O error, dev sda, sector 1527828008 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[13347.508199] EXT4-fs warning (device sda3): ext4_end_bio:342: I/O error 10 writing to inode 55050469 starting block 190978501)
[13347.508204] Buffer I/O error on device sda3, logical block 189801925
[13347.508212] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#29 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=2s
[13347.508215] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#29 Sense Key : Medium Error [current]
[13347.508217] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#29 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[13347.508219] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#29 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 5b 10 ce 68 00 00 08 00
[13347.508220] I/O error, dev sda, sector 1527828072 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[13347.508223] EXT4-fs warning (device sda3): ext4_end_bio:342: I/O error 10 writing to inode 55050469 starting block 190978509)
[13347.508225] Buffer I/O error on device sda3, logical block 189801933
[13347.508257] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#30 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=2s
[13347.508259] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#30 Sense Key : Medium Error [current]
[13347.508261] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#30 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[13347.508264] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#30 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 5b 10 ce 80 00 00 08 00
[13347.508265] I/O error, dev sda, sector 1527828096 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[13347.508267] EXT4-fs warning (device sda3): ext4_end_bio:342: I/O error 10 writing to inode 55050469 starting block 190978512)
[13347.508270] Buffer I/O error on device sda3, logical block 189801936
[13356.046988] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=3s
[13356.046998] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current]
[13356.047006] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[13356.047014] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 44 d6 17 68 00 00 08 00
[13356.047022] I/O error, dev sda, sector 1154881384 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[13360.283068] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#3 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=4s
[13360.283077] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#3 Sense Key : Medium Error [current]
[13360.283084] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#3 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[13360.283090] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#3 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 3c 07 a7 00 00 00 f8 00
[13360.283094] I/O error, dev sda, sector 1007134704 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[13360.283168] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#6 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=4s
[13360.283178] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#6 Sense Key : Medium Error [current]
[13360.283186] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#6 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[13360.283195] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#6 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 2d d0 aa b0 00 00 08 00
[13360.283200] I/O error, dev sda, sector 768649904 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x3000 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[13360.283261] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#16 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=4s
[13360.283267] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#16 Sense Key : Medium Error [current]
[13360.283273] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#16 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[13360.283278] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#16 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 5b 10 e5 88 00 00 08 00
[13360.283276] EXT4-fs error (device sda3): __ext4_find_entry:1612: inode #23726091: comm gnome-shell: reading directory lblock 0
[13360.283282] I/O error, dev sda, sector 1527833992 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[13360.283290] Aborting journal on device sda3-8.
[13360.283292] EXT4-fs warning (device sda3): ext4_end_bio:342: I/O error 10 writing to inode 55050469 starting block 190979249)
[13360.283300] Buffer I/O error on device sda3, logical block 189802673
[13360.283322] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#17 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=4s
[13360.283326] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#17 Sense Key : Medium Error [current]
[13360.283329] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#17 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[13360.283332] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#17 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 5b 10 e5 98 00 00 08 00
[13360.283335] I/O error, dev sda, sector 1527834008 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[13360.283339] EXT4-fs warning (device sda3): ext4_end_bio:342: I/O error 10 writing to inode 55050469 starting block 190979251)
[13360.283344] Buffer I/O error on device sda3, logical block 189802675
[13360.283931] EXT4-fs error (device sda3): ext4_journal_check_start:83: comm kworker/u8:1: Detected aborted journal
[13360.388651] EXT4-fs error (device sda3) in ext4_reserve_inode_write:5706: Journal has aborted
[13360.388667] EXT4-fs error (device sda3) in ext4_reserve_inode_write:5706: Journal has aborted
[13360.388717] EXT4-fs error (device sda3) in ext4_writepages:2792: Journal has aborted
[13360.445469] EXT4-fs (sda3): Remounting filesystem read-only
[13360.500964] EXT4-fs (sda3): ext4_writepages: jbd2_start: 1023 pages, ino 55061148; err -30
[13360.689931] EXT4-fs error (device sda3): ext4_dirty_inode:5902: inode #2883594: comm alacritty: mark_inode_dirty error
[13360.689957] EXT4-fs error (device sda3): ext4_dirty_inode:5902: inode #2883594: comm kworker/u8:0: mark_inode_dirty error
[13360.689975] EXT4-fs error (device sda3) in ext4_orphan_add:188: Journal has aborted
[13360.745451] EXT4-fs error (device sda3) in ext4_dirty_inode:5903: Journal has aborted
[13360.863574] EXT4-fs error (device sda3) in ext4_reserve_inode_write:5706: Journal has aborted
[13360.864710] EXT4-fs (sda3): ext4_writepages: jbd2_start: 727 pages, ino 55050469; err -30
[13361.001962] EXT4-fs (sda3): failed to convert unwritten extents to written extents -- potential data loss!  (inode 2883594, error -30)
[13364.946444] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#5 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=3s
[13364.946449] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#5 Sense Key : Medium Error [current]
[13364.946453] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#5 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[13364.946457] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#5 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 3c 07 a7 f0 00 00 08 00
[13364.946458] I/O error, dev sda, sector 1007134704 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[13368.761151] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#10 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=3s
[13368.761157] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#10 Sense Key : Medium Error [current]
[13368.761161] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#10 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[13368.761165] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#10 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 3c 07 a7 f0 00 00 08 00
[13368.761167] I/O error, dev sda, sector 1007134704 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
```

And the `lsblk` output:

```
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda             8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
├─sda1          8:1    0   498M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sda2          8:2    0     4G  0 part  /recovery
├─sda3          8:3    0   923G  0 part  /
└─sda4          8:4    0     4G  0 part
  └─cryptswap 253:0    0     4G  0 crypt [SWAP]
sr0            11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: In my opinion make a backup and replace it and you can try another cable or another port on your motherboard

Comment: Hello. Your hard drive is dead or dying. Back up the important data and replace the drive as soon as possible.

Comment: That's what I've thought :( Thank's for the info either way